# Selenium: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

My Code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-1']//a").click() # Click on Device eid

time.sleep(15)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='ping']//button[contains(text(),'Ping')]").click() # click on Ping
```

Getting error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

On Chrome and firefox xpath is correct, still getting the error? Can anyone help here, I know its a silly

[image] one.

Comment: first you would have to add url to this page so we could see full HTML. Maybe element is inside `<frame>` and you have to use `driver.switch_to.frame(...)`

Comment: Its an internal application of my company. Is there any other way?

Comment: first check if item is `<frame>`. If there is no frame then check xpath for something shorter ie. `"//table[@id='ping']"`

Comment: Thanks a Lot Furas, issue resolved, there was a frame. I implemented the frame concept. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check whether element is under `iFrame` tag, If yes then first need to switch into frame and then perform intended action.

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_name('frame_name')

driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

If its timing related issue then introduce Implicit and explicit wait in your code.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-1']//a"))
element.click()
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Thanks Narendra, it was a iFrame issue.